# Green's theorem and the unit vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering why when we calculate Green's theorem we take the scalar product of the curl? I know taking the curl of two vectors will give us a new vector perpendicular to the plane of the original vectors.

What then is the need to take the scalar procuct with the unit vector in the z plane as shown in the picture?

Thanks a lot for any help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qgRJ.png)

Comment: curl of two vectors?

Comment: apologies, meant to say curl operator acting on a vector field

Comment: Be warned: the curl of $\vec F$ need not be orthogonal to $\vec F$, despite the cross-product formula.

Comment: Would it be orthogonal to F and the curl operator?

Comment: No, the rules for cross products of vectors do not apply to $\nabla$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is circulating in the $xy$ plane.  Then the curl of F points in the direction of the unit normal $\mathbf k$

I agree with you, in this case, there is no reason to dot it with the unit normal.

However, as you move onto Stokes theorem, you will be working with surfaces that are not perpendicular to $\text {curl} F = \nabla \times F$ and to find the integral you will need  $(\nabla\times F)\cdot \mathbf n\ dS$ where $\mathbf n$ is the unit normal perpendicular to your surface.